# `import pandas` with an error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.msgpack'`

Tags: python, pandas, import

I always could run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

But I can't now, for some reason it raises:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\rep\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "C:\Users\rep\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.io.packers import read_msgpack, to_msgpack
  File "C:\Users\rep\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\packers.py", line 67, in <module>
    from pandas.msgpack import Unpacker as _Unpacker, Packer as _Packer, ExtType
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.msgpack'
>>>
```

I was thinking it must be something I did when looking at pandas source code, since I was trying to find code from there.

It still works when I write in the command line `activate updated`, but I am just wondering what happened to the pandas without `activated updated`, what did I change and how can I fix it, I looked in my folder and don't see any files named `pandas` that interrupts this process.

Comment: As the folder structure of your pandas installation shows, I'd assume your `msgpack` is under pandas\io\, thus you should change to `from pandas.io.msgpack import Unpacker as _Unpacker, Packer as _Packer, ExtType`

Comment: @yellow01 Will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future readers, I solved it long ago by copying `pandas` from the environment to outside the environment, surely I accidentally modified pandas outside the environment.

Everything works as fine now. I am pretty sure I accidentally moved `msgpack` under `io`.